# Native language text to Speech Converter

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create my native language text to speech converter.

I recorded every alphabet letters in mp3.

Here is my code:

```
private void PlayFile(string entertext)
    {
        WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
        char[] charArray = entertext.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < charArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (charArray[i].ToString() == "a")
            {
                wplayer.URL = @"E:\alphabet_audio\01_a.mp3";
                wplayer.controls.play();
            }
            else if (charArray[i].ToString() == "b")
            {
                wplayer.URL = @"E:\alphabet_audio\02_b.mp3";
                wplayer.controls.play();
            }

        }
    }
```

The problem is it's only playing last latter.

Comment: You are changing the audio before it completes. You have to wait until the wplayer completes playing the sound

Comment: How to do that? Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the file as finished playing. To do this you need to a handler to the `wplayer` object, then recursive check to make sure the previous file has finished playing.  Now this might not be the best practice because it assumes the WMP will end playing at some point, if not you have runaway recursion but in this use case I don't think it would matter.

```
  Private void PlayFile(string entertext)
  {
    //Add play state handler
    WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
    wplayer.PlayStateChange += new WMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEventHandler(wplayer_PlayStateChange);
    char[] charArray = entertext.ToCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.Length; i++)
    {
     //check play state
      PlaySound(charArray[i].ToString(), wplayer)
    }
}

Private void PlaySound(string letter, WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer)
{
    if (WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsMediaEnded == wplayer.playState)
    {
        if (letter == "a")
        {
            wplayer.URL = @"E:\alphabet_audio\01_a.mp3";
            wplayer.controls.play();
        }
        else if (letter == "b")
        {
            wplayer.URL = @"E:\alphabet_audio\02_b.mp3";
            wplayer.controls.play();
        }
     } else {
        PlaySound(letter, wplayer)
     }

 }
```

Here is some documentation on the play state enumeration: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564085(v=vs.85).aspx